# How can I save my passphrase for an SSH server in PuTTY?

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm logging into a server that I own with PuTTY on Windows. Is there any way that I can save the passphrase for my private key (like I can in the Keychain on my Mac)?

Answer (score 26):

You *can* store the passphrase for your private key, for the **current session**, using [Pageant](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant), PuTTY's SSH agent:

1. Double-click on your `.ppk` private-key file.
2. Enter the password.
3. *Optional:* For servers you trust, enable [agent forwarding](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant-forward) in *Connection → SSH → Auth*.

---

But you *cannot* store the server password itsef:

> **[A.2.8 Does PuTTY have the ability to remember my password so I don't have to type it every time?](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-password-remember)**
>
> No, it doesn't.
>
> (snip)
>
> In SSH, remembering your password would be possible in theory, but there doesn't seem to be much point since SSH supports public key authentication, which is more flexible and more secure. See [chapter 8](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey) in the documentation for a full discussion of public key authentication.

(See also [PuTTY wishlist: *remember-password*](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/remember-password.html))

---

On Windows, I have my private key passwordless but encrypted using the EFS, so it can be loaded at startup automatically but *only if I log in with my password*. (Previously I had it in a TrueCrypt volume, with that volume's keyfile on an USB drive. Don't ask me which is more secure, if at all.)

Comment: Your link A.2.8 refers to user  name/password. But you're supposedly talking about keys already, and the passphrases that go with them. I don't get it. Where is the documentation saying you can't save your key passphrase? If that is impossible, then is it possible to use a key that doesn't require a passphrase?

Answer (score 4):

You **cannot** store the passphrase for your private key *permanently* using Pagent, PuTTY's SSH key agent. You will have to store it unencrypted if you wish to avoid retyping the passphrase again and agian.

I suggest protecting all your keys with one standard easy to type passphrase.

Comment: So the program cannot even remember it while you typed it once and it stays open?